# Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException: index=1

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have been working on this application to download all the images from a webpage for about a day now, and after about 5 hours of google, no answers have turned up.  I keep getting the error message in the title along with the following logcat errors.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)
 Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: index=1
        at java.util.regex.Matcher.appendEvaluated(Matcher.java:149)
        at java.util.regex.Matcher.appendReplacement(Matcher.java:111)
        at java.util.regex.Matcher.replaceAll(Matcher.java:321)
        at java.lang.String.replaceAll(String.java:1785)
        at com.luke.test.Download$Main.getImages(Download.java:117)
        at com.luke.test.Download$Main.doInBackground(Download.java:91)
        at com.luke.test.Download$Main.doInBackground(Download.java:74)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
```

Along with the errors I have provided, I have my code as well.

```
public class Download extends Activity {
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    EditText editText;
    Button button;
    String data;
    private String URL1;
    private ImageView downloadedImg;
    private ProgressDialog simpleWaitDialog;
    String stored = null;
    private String folderPath = android.os.Build.MODEL + "\\Internal storage\\Pictures\\Screenshots\\";
    private static final String name = ".jpg";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_download);
        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                data = editText.getText().toString();
                URL1 = data;
                Log.v("URL", URL1);
                new Main().execute();
            }
        });
    }

    private class Main extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        public Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            try {


                Document doc = Jsoup.connect(URL1).get();

                Elements img = doc.getElementsByTag("img");

                for (Element el : img) {


                    String src = el.absUrl("src");
                    System.out.println("Image Found!");
                    System.out.println("src attribute is : " + src);

                    getImages(src, folderPath, name);

                }

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.err.println("There was an error");
                Logger.getLogger(Download.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

            return null;
        }

        private void getImages(String src, String folderPath, String name) throws IOException {

            int indexname = src.lastIndexOf("/");

            if (indexname == src.length()) {
                src = src.substring(1, indexname);
            }

            indexname = src.lastIndexOf("/");
            String srcname = src.substring(indexname, src.length());
            String Path = folderPath;

            String myString = Path + srcname + name;
            myString = myString.replace("?", "");
            myString = myString.replaceAll("/", "\\");
            System.out.println(myString);

            URL url = new URL(src);
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            int n = 0;
            while (-1!=(n=in.read(buf)))
            {
                out.write(buf, 0, n);
            }
            out.close();
            in.close();
            byte[] response = out.toByteArray();
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(myString);
            fos.write(response);
            fos.close();
        }

        protected void OnPostExecute(Void result) {
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

I know, it's very clunky and very over-populated with strings I am not currently using, which might be part of my problem.  So, with all that said, any help in figuring out this error would be much appreciated.

Comment: So what is in line 117? Can you confirm also that the images exist?

Comment: Well, I have successfully created the application on the PC using http://google.com, which is the test site that I have been using, and I get the same two images from google every time, so I'm pretty sure that the images exist.  As for line 117, nothing, I don't think there is anything in line 117.

Answer (score 2):

The stacktrace tells you that the problem is in this line:

```
myString = myString.replaceAll("/", "\\");
```

The two strings are used as regular expressions. This does the same but without regexes:

```
myString = myString.replace("/", "\\");
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I managed to recreate your exception with a very simple application :

```
public class Test {

     public static void main(String []args){
        String myString = "a/b";
        myString = myString.replaceAll("/", "\\");
        System.out.println(myString);
     }
}
```

This code gives :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 1
    at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.appendReplacement(Matcher.java:762)
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.replaceAll(Matcher.java:906)
    at java.lang.String.replaceAll(String.java:2162)
    at Test.main(Test.java:5)
```

Replacing `replaceAll` with `replace` solves the problem.

Another option that works is 
`myString = myString.replaceAll("/", Matcher.quoteReplacement("\\"));`

This suppresses the special meaning of `\` in the replacement string.

Answer (score 0):

The other two answers are steering you in the right direction.  This block of code:

```
int indexname = src.lastIndexOf("/");

if (indexname == src.length()) {
    src = src.substring(1, indexname);
}
```

Doesn't look right.  indexname will never equal src.length().  lastIndexOf can never return a value equal to the length of the search string.  It will always a value between [0,length-1] or -1 in the case of no match.